# Go to previous activity in non-activity class

Tags: java, android

I got a problem I made a class for Alert Dialogs now if someone presses Ok it should go back to the previous activity but I don't know how to do this, because when i put in finsih(); it gives me an error here is my code:

```
package com.laurenswuyts.find.it;

import com.laurenswuyts.find.it.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;



public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
     *               - pass null if you don't want icon
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {

            }





        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

In the public void Onclick i tried to type finish(); but that didnt work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Comment: try dialog.dismiss();

Comment: @aegean makes me realise that your question isn't clear - do you want the previous activity, or just the activity that launched the dialog? (ie, hiding the dialog)

Comment: Haven't you solved this problem. Both Adam's and mine answers are what you were looking for I guess. Mark one of them as answer and close this question if it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a property to your manager;

```
Context context;
```

Init it on your `showAlertDialog()` method.

Under your click;

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Comment: Make sure you're not passing applicationContext though! Have to pass the activity context

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the click listener in from the calling activity:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener clickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
AlertDialogManager manager = new AlertDialogManager();
manager.showAlertDialog(this, title, message, status, clickListener);
```

Then in your `AlertDialogManager`, you change the method like this:

```
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
        Boolean status, DialogInterface.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    if(status != null)
        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", clickListener);

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

This way the click behaviour is handled by the calling class, and the `AlertDialogManager` doesn't have any knowledge of what happens after OK is clicked.